# Navigate to next page after API post response success?

Tags: json, api, flutter, postman

i'm trying to map this data so i can navigate to next screen in flutter, but i have no idea if
i'm correct with this code

SEND DATA TO THE SERVER

```
Future login(String email, String password) async {
  String myUrl = Uri.encodeFull('http://192.168.1.00:8000/api/login');
  http.post(myUrl, body: {
    "email": email,
    "password": password,
  }).then((response) {
    print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response body : ${response.body}');

    Map mapValue = json.decode(response.body);
    print('Token value : ${mapValue.values.toString()}');

    Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
    // return data;
    print('This, ${data['email']}');
    print('let, ${data['password']}');
  });
}
```

After i press button i want to move to next screen

MY BUTTON

```
child: RaisedButton(
    textColor: Colors.white,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Text('Login'),
    onPressed: () async {
    await login(emailController.text, passwordController.text)
    .then((value) {
    if (value['data']) {
    Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewPage()));
    } else {
    print('failed');
    }
   });
  print(emailController.text);
  print(passwordController.text);
  },
))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the response status code to check whether the data successfully send and redirect to the next page

```
    Future login(String email, String password) async {
      String myUrl = Uri.encodeFull('http://192.168.1.00:8000/api/login');
      http.post(myUrl, body: {
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
      }).then((response) {
        print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');
        print('Response body : ${response.body}');
    
        Map mapValue = json.decode(response.body);
        print('Token value : ${mapValue.values.toString()}');
    
        Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
        // return data;
        print('This, ${data['email']}');
        print('let, ${data['password']}');
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
        //if you want replace current page with the next one
        Navigator.pushReplace(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()));
        }else{
        scaffoldKey.currentState
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Something went wrong!!!")));}
      });
    }
```